# Header lines over margin

Tags: tables, header-footer, rules

Why are my header toprules, midrules, and bottomrules going over the limit of the text's body?
What can I do make these lines/rules align perfectly with the body text limit?

Thank you.

[image]

```
% PREAMBLE

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,noparindent,noparskip]{bookest}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{palatino} % Font for document
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{titletoc} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltxtable} % Instead of Longtable package %\caption package is offered with \Longtable
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array} % For long tables, to define width of columns
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

{\small
\begin{longtable}{r>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}p{2.1cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.3cm}}
    \caption{wegergegeg} \label{Rulers} \\
    \toprule
    No. & Name \& Title & Dates & Events \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption*{\autoref{Rulers} (\textit{Continued})} \\
    \toprule
    No. & Name \& Title & Dates & Events \\
    \midrule
    \endhead    
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table columns are too wide, that's the cause.If you reduce `7.3cm` to `7.15cm` it seems to fit, but in fact, you should use `ltablex` etc.

Comment: You're right, but it's annoying, on my actual document, which is too huge for me to paste here, it doesn't work. I guess I'm going to have to look into ltablex. What do you mean by etc.?

Comment: etc. (and its features) or `tabularx` if you know that the table does need to break over pages

Comment: By compilation on the command line LaTeX tells you exactly that there are overfull hboxes

Comment: Any reason for using [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)?

Comment: Werner: no particular reason. It seemed to work ... until I noticed that misalignment issue.

Comment: Comments aside: needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor`. Also, I'm not sure `tocloft` and `titletoc` are compatible. Last, `palatino` is obsolete and should be replaced with `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`.

Comment: Christian: no surprises there. The original document is itself very text heavy: that longtable is full of long lines, particularly the right hand column. I'll get back to it tomorrow and try to figure it out. If not I'll upload a new version of the code. Thank you for your time.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Bernard: thank you for that. I need to get in there and clean things up. More work!

Comment: By the way, I found the solution: I had a three-column spanning horizontal column inside the four-column longtable that was too long by a few mm. I shortened it ... and it works fine now. Thanks again everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace `longtable` with the `tabularx` version from `ltablex` and the last columntype to be `X` instead of `p{7.3cm}`.

This will use the full linewidth, provided the `\keepXColumns` command has been used.

A manual regulation of column width is error prone and tedious.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,noparindent,noparskip]{bookest}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{palatino} % Font for document
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{titletoc} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ltxtable} % Instead of Longtable package %\caption package is offered with \Longtable
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array} % For long tables, to define width of columns
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\keepXColumns
\begin{document}

{\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}p{2.1cm}X}
    \caption{wegergegeg} \label{Rulers} \\
    \toprule
    No. & Name \& Title & Dates & Events \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption*{\autoref{Rulers} (\textit{Continued})} \\
    \toprule
    No. & Name \& Title & Dates & Events \\
    \midrule
    \endhead    
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\
    1& eytwety & etwet & etwt \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works here ... but not in my document for some reason. If I change the centimetres, the space reserved for the text changes of course, but the rule lines remain extended a bit beyond the body text limit. Strange. Gonna have to investigate more.

Comment: @nofare: Well, this is difficult to tell if you have a different setup

Comment: Indeed. Thought I had done a good job copying the problematic code over.